# flowplayer plays video again after closing fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, flowplayer

i'm using jquery to place video with flowplayer skin in a hidden div in my page to make it play in fancybox

```
$("a.videoLink").click(function(){
    var videoFile = "products_video/" + $(this).attr("videofile");
    var videoPoster = $(this).attr("videofile");
var videoCode = '<a href='+videoFile+' id="player" style="display:block;width:600px;height:400px;"></a><script language="JavaScript">flowplayer("player", "flowplayer-3.2.7.swf")</script>';
    $("#videoPlayer").html(videoCode);
    $.fancybox({
        'transitionIn' : 'fade',
        'transitionOut' : 'fade',
        'href' : '#videoPlayer'
        });
    });
```

this is the hidden div

```
<div style="display: none;">
<div id="videoPlayer"></div>
</div>
```

when i click any of the images of the video it starts playing in fancybox but the problem is when i close the fancybox video starts playing from the beginning in the hidden div
how to stop the video if the fancybox is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the API options in your script, I assume you are using fnacybox v1.3.x, aren't you?

What is happening here is that fancybox ***moves*** the inline content into the fancybox container and leaves a `temp` container inside the hidden `DIV` instead. Then your video starts playing inside the modal box.

When you close fancybox, it removes the `temp` container and ***moves back*** the content from the fancybox container into the inline hidden `DIV`, so your video starts playing again there (as it did when it was *moved* into fancybox).

As a workaround, try adding these two options to your fancybox script:

```
'onClosed': function() {
 $("#videoPlayer").empty();
},
'onCleanup': function() {
 var myContent = this.href;
 $(myContent).unwrap();
}
```

The first option removes the video from the hidden inline content (so no more video in the background) and the second option fixes a bug [described here](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/fab7b6d81a173b33) when working with inline content.

So the part of the fancybox script should look like:

```
// videoCode script here etc
$.fancybox({
 'transitionIn' : 'fade',
 'transitionOut' : 'fade',
 'href' : '#videoPlayer',
 'onClosed': function() {
  $("#videoPlayer").empty();
 },
 'onCleanup': function() {
  var myContent = this.href;
  $(myContent).unwrap();
 } 
}); // fancybox
// close click and ready etc
```

Comment: thanks a lot i made this : making the div containing the temp which is inside the hidden div to display block and when i click close fancybox it makes it display none so it never shows on my page and gets empty when closing fancybox thanks

Comment: This works perfectly with the one note, if you're using version 2 the callbacks are beforeClose and afterClose respectively.

Comment: @DavidFairbanks : the solution above is for fancybox v1.3.4. If you are using version 2.x then you don't need the `afterClose` callback at all since the latest version doesn't have the bug fixed in the `onCleanup` callback (v1.3.4)